# Create template method that uses reflection to create object

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a template method that needs to instantiate class objects with given class name string using reflection. The case is a bit complicated since the returning class is an implementation of an interface which also uses a type variable. I would like to pass the class name string and the type of the type variable of the interface and create the class object. Here is an example method signature:

```
<T> Class<? extends Foo<T>> 
createClassObject(String className, Class<T> classTypeVariable);
```

Is it possible to implement this method in Java 1.5 without any warnings or any usage of @SuppressWarnings annotation?

EDIT: example method signature edited thanks to Thomas comment.

Comment: Shouldn't `classTypeVariable` be `Class<T>` rather than an instance of `T`?

Comment: Btw, do you really _create_ a class at runtime or just look it up? Or do you want to create an instance of that class, i.e. an object?

Comment: @Thomas, I use the returning result of Class.forName() which is a Class<?> object.

Comment: By the way, from the home page of StackOverflow site I can see that there are few answers but when I open the page of the question itself I can't see any answers? I can see only the comments related to the question. Am I missing something or it is a sign that I need to go home already?

Comment: @jilt3d: I saw an answer on this page earlier, but it was erroneous (it returned a `T` rather than a `Class<...>`). Presumably the person who posted that answer realized on his/her own that it was erroneous, and so deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to achieve that without any warnings or any usage of @SuppressWarnings annotation. That's because Class.forName() will be typed as Class. Any attempt to cast it to something more concrete (e.g, something along the lines `Class<? extends Foo<T>>`) will yield a type-erasure-related warning. The same happens if you try to cast Class.forName().newInstance().

That said, I think this method is the prime example for a positive use of @SuppressWarnings. I don't see any problem using this annotation in such cases. Of course, you may want to add some logic that cheks that `Class.forName(className)` does extend `Foo<T>`, to make sure the castings are sound. Note that this runtime checks do not make the method more fragile: when you have a `Class.forName()` call in your method, you already have a potential runtime type error.

Comment: It is possible to cast a `Class<?>` to something more concrete using `Class.asSubclass()`, for example if it were a string class I could do `Class.forName(className).asSubclass(String.class)`. It doesn't work in this case because the subclass (`Foo`) is parameterized.

Comment: @Kevin K: it is exactly I was trying to do!

Answer (score 1):

If the returned class is supposed to be generic (`Bar<T> extends Foo<T>` or whatnot), then I'm pretty confident that it's not possible, since (due to erasure) the type system has no way to check at run-time if the class that `Class.forName(...)` returned is a `Class<Bar<T>>` as opposed to a `Class<Bar<U>>` or something. (There's actually just a single `Class` object representing all `Bar<...>` types, but the type system doesn't have a representation for that, so it pretends that `Class<Bar<T>>` and `Class<Bar<U>>` are completely separate objects with different types.) About the closest you can get is something like this:

```
<T> Class<? extends Iterable<T>> createClassObject
        (final String className, final Class<T> clazz) throws Exception
    { return Class.forName(className).asSubclass(getIterableTClass(clazz)); }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> Class<? extends Iterable<T>> getIterableTClass(final Class<T> clazz)
    { return (Class<? extends Iterable<T>>)(Class<?>)Iterable.class; }
```

where you use an unchecked cast to trick the compiler into thinking that it has enough information about `Foo<T>` (in this case `Iterable<T>`) to do an `asSubclass` check.

However, if the returned class is *not* supposed to be generic (`Bar extends Foo<String>` or whatnot), then I'm not sure; I've never dealt much with the parts of reflection that deal with that, though I know they exist. I'm pretty sure they'd allow you to examine enough of `Bar`'s inheritance hierarchy to determine if it really extends `Foo<String>`, but I really don't know if they'd give you a way to make the compiler aware that you've done so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done. In NetBeans IDE 7 I do not get any warnings.

**CORRECTION:** sorry this cannot work, there is no Class construction. Of course you could use a ClassLoader, proxy class or ASM.

```
public class Bar<T> extends Foo<T> {
}
```

It really is logical and simple. The clue probably is doing a chained newInstance().

```
    public <T> Class<? extends Foo<T>> createClassObject(String className, Class<T> classTypeVariable) {
    try {
        Class<? extends Class> resultType = Bar.class.getClass();
        return resultType.getConstructor(classTypeVariable).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}
```